# How to make box thinner in pyplot.boxplot

Tags: matplotlib, boxplot

When I use boxplot, only for one set of data (i.e. one array), my box is actually stretched to the entire width of the window: 
[screenshot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UsQl.png)

I tried to use "widths"-parameter in plt.boxplot but it does not change anything:

[code's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2zXr.png)

I would like make the box thinner (let's say 30% of window or so).  What I am doing wrong?

Comment: For next time, don't paste your code in form of an image, but rather paste it as text, such that it can easily copied from the question. Also consider taking the [Tour] to learn more about how SO works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
plt.tight_layout(pad=10)
#10 spaces in font size units between figure and window border
plt.show()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have v.0.99.1.1 which does not have tight_layout method

Comment: Do you have `plt.axes` which allows you to pass the size of the window in (0,1) coordinates, for instance `plt.axes( (0,0,1,1))` for a full size window, try `plt.axes((.25,.25,.5.5))` in your case.

Comment: Ok, 
I got some improvement by using plt.axes((.8,0.8,0.8,0.8)).
At least this looks much better.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The x axis is autoscaled to the range of the box' extention. This problem seems to only occur in matplotlib versions prior to 2.0.

One easy way to avoid this is to set some limits on the xaxis, like

```
plt.xlim(0.5, 1.5)
```

One may then play around with the limits until it looks most appealing.

Comment: Yes, I have very old version 0.99.1.1 (and cannot upgrade it due to client's limitation).
I tried this .xlim (big, small values) but unfortunately it does not change the result.

Comment: I don't have any version older than 1.5 available here. So that leaves me guessing. One option might be to plot transparent (or white)  points at positions 0.5 and 1.5 for example. `plt.plot([0.5, 1.5],[0,0],linestyle="", color="w", alpha=0.0)`.